# Get inner text of an element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the text following the element, in JavaScript, but without the classicals workarounds. My markup is:

```
<div class='el'>
  <span class='fa fa-user'></span> Dollynho
</div>
```

I just want the word 'Dollynho', but without spliting the innerHTML of `.el`. I can do it this way:

```
var xs = document.getElementsByClassName('el')[0]
console.log(xs.split('>')[2].trim()) # => "Dollynho"
```

Can I do it in a cleaner way? (No-regex, pls)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a pointer: beware the text returned is not cross-browser constant. Some browsers will return spaces and `\n` along with the text string, others won't. So don't rely on that if you are comparing the text to some string, try trimming (and possibly removing inner spaces) before comparing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var xs = document.getElementsByClassName('el')[0];
xs.innerText;
```

in firefox you may need to user `textContent`

Comment: Let's not forget the `[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all the childNodes and grab the content of the child nodes of type text, then remove the spureous \n

```
var childNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('el')[0].childNodes;

var textContent = "";
for(var i=0; i<childNodes.length; i++) {
    if(childNodes[i].nodeType==3  ) {
        textContent+=childNodes[i].data;
    }
}
textContent= textContent.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,"");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/53rx1t0o/11/

Comment: This is the best answer so far, because not only does it work for the example case, it would also work if the text preceded the span, if there were multiple spans (or other elements), and if there were multiple text nodes.  Plus, it has the best cross- browser support.  Consider replacing \r in addition to \n.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Good point! Updated answer with a more clever replace.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your script code if you want the html of your .el class is retrieved:

var x = $(".el").html();

Answer (score 0):

You could get the text using jquery

```
$(".el").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your IE support needs you could use textContent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

```
var xs = document.getElementsByClassName('el')[0]
console.log(cs.textContent)  # => "Dollynho"
```

IE has .innerText which works similarly but with some caveats (described on the textContent page above)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899(v=vs.85).aspx